# Authorize.Net run tests in production live mode

Tags: testing, authorize.net

Using Authorize.Net, we know you can run tests in test mode in production.  We can run tests in live mode or test mode in the sandbox.  Can you run tests in production live mode with real credit card numbers and security codes?  We are using the API and I can not find any documentation that says we can do this.

We do not want to charge the credit card when testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean can you take a real credit card and make a payment? Of course. Just be careful as using your own credit card to make a payment to yourself technically is not allowed but doing it once to verify an integration never raises a red flag.

Comment: No we just want to run the tests in production live mode without charging the credit cards.

Comment: There's no way to do that. Live is live and everything counts. But you shouldn't need to do that. All of the other ways of testing will validate everything works for you. The closest you can come is to void the transaction after is has been processed.